# Windows Server 2003 - DISKPART: The volume you have selected may not be extended

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-server-2003, hyper-v, diskpart

I'm trying to resize a disk on a Windows 2003 server.  Via Disk Management I can see one drive (C) and 73.01GB of Unallocated space.  This instance is running on Hyper-V.

In DISKPART I selected the volume and typed extend but was presented with the error:

"The volume you have selected may not be extended"
"Please select another volume and try again."

Comment: Do you have the hotfix described here applied - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841650?

Comment: Use this tool ExtPart from Dell
http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=R64398